# What is the method for finding $\int\frac {x^3 + 5x^2 +2x -4}{(x^4-1)}\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$
\int\frac {x^3 + 5x^2 +2x -4}{(x^4-1)}dx
$$
A bit confused with how to integrate this question. I though it was partial fractions but was unsure about the what to do after that.

Comment: What did you get for your partial fraction decomposition?  That might be where your stuck (but we can't guess because you're giving us no hints about what you've tried, what's (partially) working and what is not), but without some insight about what is and isn't working for you, we can only guess.

Comment: What was wrong with partial fractions?

Comment: Please modify the title. Title with only expressions makes it difficult to search for others

Answer (score 3):

The integral can be written as

$$I=\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{4x^3}{x^4-1}+5\int\frac{x^2}{(x^2-1)(x^2+1)}+\int\frac{2x}{(x^2-1)(x^2+1)}-4\int\frac{dx}{(x^2-1)(x^2+1)}=I_1+I_2+I_3+I_4$$

$$I_1=\frac{1}{4}ln|x^4-1|+C$$

$$I_2=\frac{5}{2}\int\frac{1}{x^2-1}+\int\frac{1}{x^2+1}$$

$$I_3=\int\frac{dt}{(t-1)(t+1)}$$ where $t=x^2$

$$I_4=-2\int\frac{1}{x^2-1}-2\int\frac{1}{x^2+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Partial Solution**

Well, assuming you did the partial fraction decomposition already (as you said you did), you should get the following integral
$$\int\left(\frac{9-x}{2(x^2+1)}+\frac{1}{x-1}+\frac{1}{2 (x+1)}\right) dx$$
$$=\frac{9}{2}\int\frac {dx}{x^2+1} - \frac{1}{2}\int \frac {x}{x^2+1}dx + \int \frac{dx}{x-1}+ \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{dx}{x+1}$$
A.) $\quad \int\frac {dx}{x^2+1}$ = $\arctan x$
B.) $\quad\int \frac {x}{x^2+1}dx = \frac{1}{2}\int \frac {du}{u+1} = \frac{1}{2}\log (u+1) = \frac{1}{2}\log (x^2+1)$
C.)$\quad\int \frac{dx}{x-1} = \log(x-1)$
D.)$\quad\int \frac{dx}{x+1} = \log(x+1)$

Comment: Actually i did get this answer but the 9/2 was not something i got and sorry for the lack of solution. A bit tired from pulling all nighters.

Comment: @Nicholas yup. Absolutely right... perhaps it's time for me to get some sleep too :P thanks.